# Postfix: What does "If your machine is a mail server for its entire domain" indicate?

Tags: postfix, email-server

**Environment:** Postfix 3.3, Centos 8, Digital Ocean Droplet

I'm reading the Postfix [basic configuration readme](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html) and I came across a definition I don't fully understand.

Under the heading, **What domains to receive mail for** it goes over the `mydestination` parameter and includes this sentence,

> IMPORTANT: If your machine is a mail server for its entire domain, you
>   must list `$mydomain` as well.

I believe that warning is referring to this line in `main.cf`.  Below is the default value.

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
```

Unfortunately I'm not exactly sure what that warning means.

On my server I have an NGINX reverse proxy, a Node.js Express server and the Postfix/Dovecot setup.

**Question:**  Because I only have a single mail server does that mean it covers my whole domain and I need to use `$mydomain`?  Or are they saying that because I also use the server as a web server the mail server doesn't represent the entire use of the domain and I shouldn't include `$mydomain`?  Does it mean something else?  I can't tell what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessaryly, you can delegate a mail destinated to a subdomain to another server. For for instance: example.com use a diferente server than submain.example.com that's mean you are using two postfix server.

If you set:

> ```
> mydestination = $myhostname, subdomain.$mydomain
> ```

You are saying "OK Accept mail destinate to "hostname" and subdomain.example.com

Edited: You can use a diferente public IPs for each postfix server or subdomain.